# how to change real time node information in javafx?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I'm trying to change the value of a string that is in another method with an event in a button, but when clicking nothing happens.

```
public class Test extends Application{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Objeto1 root = new Objeto1();

    Scene scene = new Scene(root.first());
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

}
```

Objeto1

```
public class Objeto1 {
String tmp ="hola";
public Objeto1() {
}
public VBox first(){
    VBox root = new VBox();
    setTmp("hola");
    HBox button = new HBox();
    Button btn = new Button("cliclk");
    btn.setOnAction(e->{
        setTmp("");
    });
    button.getChildren().add(btn);

    HBox a = form();

    root.getChildren().addAll(button,a);


    return root;
}
public HBox form(){
    HBox root = new HBox();
    Label lab = new Label(getTmp());
    root.getChildren().add(lab);
    return root;
}

public String getTmp() {
    return tmp;
}

public void setTmp(String tmp) {
    this.tmp = tmp;
}

}
```

I would like to click on the content of the string change and show in the label the change

Comment: then simply do it :) You don't expect any of us to write the code for you, right? If you can't right away, read and understand a basic tutorial, apply what you learned and when stuck come back with a [mcve] that demonstrates what you want to achieve and how it doesn't work. Your current code may be a good starting point, just add the clicking-and-change part.

Comment: sorry my english is a little bad, the question is if it is possible with the structure that has to change the information in real time and to be displayed

Comment: Use `Label.setText`. Of course for that to work you need to store the label in a field...

Comment: @fabian Thank you. That's what I needed.